# How to make a text field scrollable?

Tags: react-native, text

I am trying to create a calculator, but I am facing a problem when the text gets long because it turns into an ellipsis, so I used `ScrollView`. It can be scrolled by increasing the value of `numberOfLines`, but when I tried scrolling up, it bounced back, and I would like it to stay where it is scrolled.

I set `adjustsFontSizeToFit` to `true` but it gets smaller too much which is not the one I want.

You can test it from here https://snack.expo.dev/_i4anOJ8v

Here is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWO8Y.jpg

Any help is appreciated

```
<View style={styles.fieldContainer}>
  <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.field}>
    <Text
      // adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}
      numberOfLines={500}
      style={{
        fontSize: textFontSize,
      }}>
      {text}
    </Text>
  </ScrollView>
</View>;


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  fieldContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
  },
  field: {
    marginTop: 'auto',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

==> you need to change your style in scrollview.

```
 field: {
    
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    flexDirection: "column",
  },
```

Comment: Hi, I would like to show the text from top to bottom.

Comment: I have edited my answer. please check and let me know.